# How to stop cats from chewing on cords

Tags: cats, behavior

My cats have been chewing on various cords throughout the house. The cords to the sound system and the wifi router have been particular favorite targets, and last night they rendered our speakers completely inoperable. Does anyone have experience with this behavior? Is there something I can do to deter it, or to prevent them from chewing on the cords, or make the cords un-chewable? Recommendations for something to wrap the cords in, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to make cords unpalatable or less appealing to chew.  You can get purpose made products; either a bitter apple spray from the pet store, or a cord cover (sometimes sold as a cord tunnel).

If you want to set up an immediate solution with things you have at home, wrapping cords in a few layers of aluminum foil or some packing tape, sticky side out, makes chewing unappealing to most cats.